# Specifying different return type object in a single method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, c#-4.0

I am trying to load different disparate objects such as Person, Address etc from a file via a single method call. I should be able to somehow provide return type in the method call and expect the same objects to be returned by the method.

Example:

```
var myAbstractClass = new MyAbstractClass()
Person person = myAbstractClass.Load(source) -- Expecting to return Person 
Address addr = myAbstractClass.Load(source) -- Same call but this time expecting to return Address
```

Currently the Load() method loads the different objects, but I am struggling to figure out the return type that matches with the request. I would like to know if this is something that can be achieved using Generics?

Here's the snippet of the code for reference:

```
public abstract class DataLoader
 {
    public abstract void Load(Source dataSoure);
 } 

public class AddressLoader : DataLoader
{
       public override void Load(Source dataSoure)        
       {
         //Load Address
       }
}

public class PersonLoader : DataLoader
{
       public override void Load(Source dataSoure)        
       {
         //Load Person
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solution is to make DataLoader as generic class:

```
public abstract class DataLoader<T>
 {
    public abstract T Load(Source dataSoure);
 } 

public class AddressLoader : DataLoader<AddressClass>
{
    public override AddressClass Load(Source dataSoure)        
    {
       //Load Address
       //return new AddressClass(...);
    }
}

public class PersonLoader : DataLoader<PersonClass>
{
    public override PersonClass Load(Source dataSoure)        
    {
       //Load Person
       //return new PersonClass(...);
    }
}
```